# Does an inner product exist for every base such that that base is orthonogal

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

I am not asking if we can build an orthogonal vector space using GS algorithm.

> Let $V$ be a finite vector space with basis $B$, show that exists an inner product
>   $b(\cdot,\cdot )$ such that $V$ is orthogonal under $b$.

At first, I thought of defining $b(x, y)=[x^T]_B[I]_B[y]_B=[x^T]_B[y]_B$, it works, but how do I prove it?

Comment: Yes, that works. What are you stuck on proving?

Comment: I am stuck on showing bi-linearity of $b$

Comment: @mfl
Then $v_1=(1,0), v_2=(1,1)$ and $[v_1]_B=(1,0), [v_2]_B=(0,1)$, and $[v_1]_B^T[v_2]_B=0$

Comment: Do you know / do you know how to show that matrix multiplication is bilinear?

Comment: Yes, can I say that  $[cv+u]_B=[v]_B+[u]_B$ where $c\in F$ and $u,v\in V$?

Answer (score 0):

We just need to show linearity of $b$.

Let $x,y,z\in V, \alpha \in F$

$$b(\alpha x+y,z)=\left<[\alpha x+y]_B, [z]_B\right>=\left<\alpha[x]_B+[y]_B, [z]_B\right>=\left<\alpha[x]_B,[z]_B\right>+\left<[y]_B+[z]_B\right>=\alpha b(x,z)+b(y,z)$$

And then, $b$ is linear; it also follows that for any $v_i, v_j \in B$ where $i \ne j$, $\left<[v_i]_B, [v_j]_B\right>=0$